# MVC dropdrown not getting the value in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a drop down using razor filling a list of a model and then passing this list to the view to fill the drop down. The drop down is created correctly but when I post the value to the create action of the controller i'm not getting the drop down value.

The model, in the IdCarBrand I return the dropdown value, who is filled with the list DropDownList :

```
public class CarModelModel
{
    public int IdCarBrand { get; set; }
    //Drop down
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownList { get; set; }
}
```

Then I populate the list with this method, service just access to the database:

```
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItemsDropDown()
       {
        SelectListItem listItem = null;
        CarBrandService service = new CarBrandService();
        var itemsList = service.GetAll().Select(x => 
            new SelectListItem{
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });

        return new SelectList(itemsList, "Value", "Text");
       }
```

and also in the controller I have the default creation actions

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

    }
```

Here in the model variable is where the

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,URL,Email,Img")] CarModelModel brand)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(brand);
    }
```

Now in the view I've got this code to create the dropdrown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdCarBrand, Model.DropDownList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

The html rendered is:

```
<select name="IdCarBrand" id="IdCarBrand" htmlattributes="{ class = form-control }" data-val-required="The IdCarBrand field is required." data-val-number="The field IdCarBrand must be a number." data-val="true" class="valid">
<option value="1">Alfa Romeo</option>
<option value="2">Audi</option>
<option value="3">BMW</option>
<option value="4">Chery</option>
<option value="5">Chrevrolet</option>.......
```

In conclusion, the drop down is show perfectly.
I've got two issues:

1- In the Create Action, IdCarBrand returns null.

2- Visually the dropdown it's not taking the class form control:

Comment: You have a `[Bind]` attribute that excludes property `IdCarBrand` (its not in the `Include` property list)

Comment: Can you explain it with more detail, I didn't understand.

Comment: There is also no need to create you `SelectList` twice. - it can be simply 1 line of code `return new SelectList(service.GetAll(), "Id", "Name");`

Comment: The `[Bind(Include = "..")]` specifies the properties to be included when binding to a model. All properties not in the list are excluded (so your property `IdCarBrand` is not not bound). Note by default all properties are bound so you can just remove the `[Bind]` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your action .. you've not INCLUDED it.

```
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,URL,Email,Img,IdCarBrand")] CarModelModel brand)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    return View(brand);
}
```

By creating an include list, you've excluded it.

For the drop down.. modify as below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdCarBrand, Model.DropDownList,new { @class = "form-control" })
```